# Spring boot jackson conversion not working on local environment

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jackson

I am having spring boot 1.4.2 app. I am using jackson version 2.7.0.
When I am calling any POST api with json as a request. I am getting 400 as a response code in server logs and in response body I get "fieldName:may not be empty" as a message in front of that field.
This issue occurs only on local environment and it is working fine on deployment server environment.
I have tried all possible combinations like locally making maven,java version same as on server. But its of no use.
Local OS is MAC and deployment environment is LINUX.

Pom looks like as below:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

Spring boot Main class looks like below:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml", "classpath:*-servlet.xml" })
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.abc.test" })
public class MainApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Autowired
    Filter customRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter;

    static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MainApplication.class);

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return configureApplication(builder);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApplication.class, args);
    }

    private static SpringApplicationBuilder configureApplication(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(MainApplication.class).bannerMode(Banner.Mode.CONSOLE);
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean remoteDispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        registration.setName("remote");
        registration.addUrlMappings("/1.0/test/*");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean jsonDispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        registration.setName("json");
        registration.addUrlMappings("/1.0/rest/*", "/1.1.1/rest/*", "/1.2/rest/*", "/rest/v1.2/*");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean xmlDispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        registration.setName("xml");
        registration.addUrlMappings("/1.0/some/search");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean swaggerDispatcherRegistration(DispatcherServlet dispatcherServlet) {
        ServletRegistrationBean registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(dispatcherServlet);
        registration.setName("swagger");
        registration.addUrlMappings("/api-docs", "/swagger-resources", "/swagger-ui.html");
        return registration;
    }

    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean rewriteFilterConfig() {
        FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        //some filter related stuff
        return reg;
    }


    @Bean
    public FilterRegistrationBean customRqHdrAuthFilterConfig() {

        FilterRegistrationBean registration = new FilterRegistrationBean();
        registration.setFilter(customRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter);
        registration.addUrlPatterns("/*");
        registration.setName("customRequestHeaderAuthenticationFilter");
        registration.setDispatcherTypes(DispatcherType.REQUEST, DispatcherType.FORWARD, DispatcherType.INCLUDE, DispatcherType.ERROR);
        registration.setOrder(1);
        return registration;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you say this " This issue occurs only on local environment and it is working fine on deployment server environment." , this means there could be a deployment problem. So check the application deployed on local and server. Also, add some more details to question like URL used, method signature on controller class.

Comment: Hi Gourav, I have checked jar built on server and local. Both jars have same content. The difference is that on server I have added my application as a service and I start app through init.d. On local I do java -jar app.jar. I am not getting why its not working on local as both jars have same content.

Comment: Is your application a Spring Boot Application? Can you share what have you got in your main class?

Comment: Hi Ashwin, Yes my application is Spring boot application. Here is content of my main class.

Comment: Hi Ashwin, Yes my application is Spring boot application. I have updated question with main class content. Please check and let me know what you think the root cause for this issue might be.